# PHP - How to check result of successful query for updating in Adodb?

Tags: php, adodb

How to check result of successful (or not) query for updating in Adodb?

My code :

```
$query = "Update tableA set name = 'myname' where id = 1";

$res = $dbConn->Execute($query);
```

I tried $res->FieldCount() and $res->RowCount() and $res->RecordCount() but not working.

Comment: What does it mean "not working"?

Comment: the result of these methods are always 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i dont remember wrongly, use

```
Affected_Rows( )
```

Comment: undefined method ADORecordSet_empty::affected_rows()

Comment: echo "res".$res->affected_rows();

Comment: try $dbConn->affected_rows();

Comment: maybe a dumb question, but better check, in ur table in database, id 1 got record?

Comment: that sounds weird to me, can you post more script, so i can duplicate on  my side.

Comment: I wrote $dbConn->affected_rows() after $dbConn->CompleteTrans(), maybe this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = $dbConn->Prepare('UPDATE....');

if($dbConn->Execute($sql) === false) {
  print '<div>error update[1]: '.$dbConn->ErrorMsg().'</div>';
 }

if($dbConn->affected_rows() == 0) {}
```